# In layman's terms, what is the difference between OpenAthens and Shibboleth?

Tags: databases

I Googled. I don't have Ph.D. computer science to understand [What is the difference between Shibboleth and OpenAthens?](https://openathens.org/informationmanager-faqs/difference-shibboleth-openathens/) Too many esoteric words! I  Googled SAML and found [Security Assertion Markup Language](https://www.varonis.com/blog/what-is-saml/), but  I don't have time to learn new computer  language! I already trouble English. English is not my first language.

> Shibboleth is Open Source software that provides single sign-on infrastructure and supports the SAML standard, as well as other protocols. Shibboleth is usually installed and managed by an institution or publisher.
>
> OpenAthens supports many of the same standards, including SAML but is delivered as a cloud-based solution, supported by a service desk and team of technical specialists who are on hand to assist with setup, integration, and operation. OpenAthens and Shibboleth can happily interoperate, as they are based on many of the same international standards.

Then I try second link on Google.  [Hein Online](https://help.heinonline.org/kb/does-heinonline-support-shibbolethathens)

> [image]

Now I baffled even more! Shibboleth "federations"? "metadata"?

Other sites list OpenAthens but not Shibboleth. Please explain all this like I'm 5?

Comment: When I log in to my university computer account, I see "shibboleth" in the URL of the login page, but that does not convince me that this question has anything to do with academia. I"m inclined to guess that shibboleth is a generic authentication system used by all sorts of computer networks, not just academic ones.

Comment: How is this your business, in the first place?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler  I don't own these companies. I don't work in them. Just trying to use these websites.

Comment: @ParkKiHyun I see you got a complete answerr. However, as a regular user you are actually not supposed to know these names at all. I just thought you might need help to set up a SSO. This should not happen out of the blue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Shibboleth Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth_Single_Sign-on_architecture) is a good place to start.

> Shibboleth is a single sign-on log-in system.... It allows people to sign in using just one identity to various systems run by federations of different organizations or institutions. The federations are often universities or public service organizations.

So, Shibboleth is a software program that large organizations can use to handle having users sign in. It's free software that the organizations can download and use. One nice thing about it is that it supports interoperability: for example, two affiliated universities can form a "federation" within Shibboleth. This allows them to each provide content to their students without sharing content with each other. Better yet, students enrolled at both universities won't need two separate accounts. But, Shibboleth must be set up and maintained by the institutions themselves.

As your link above says, OpenAthens is very similar -- it is more-or-less a large Shibboleth  federation that is managed by a non-profit and comes with a dedicated IT team and help desk. So, a university could just pay to join OpenAthens, and OpenAthens' own employees would help to set everything up, maintain it, and provide user support. Since many institutions use OpenAthens, it is convenient for the end-user as well -- they can use one account for many different content providers, even content providers who don't have any direct relationship with each other.

Note, this is not exclusive to Academia -- large businesses could use this software as well. But in my experience, many people encounter these concepts when dealing with universities or academic publishers.